# Maximum call stack size exceeded in kendo Tree List

Tags: jquery, angular, kendo-treelist

I implement kendo Tree List but i got some problem as following:

> **RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
>
>   at init._defaultParentId**

**Code:**

```
var bindingData = [{ "RateTypeID": 1, "c": null, "Type": "abc", "based": "xyz" },
                    { "RateTypeID": 1, "c": 1, "Type": "pqr", "based": "xyz" },
                    { "RateTypeID": 3, "c": 1, "Type": "mno", "based": "xyz" }];
var dataSource = new kendo.data.TreeListDataSource({
                    data: bindingData,
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            id: "RateTypeID",
                            parentId:"c",
                            fields: {
                                RateTypeID: { field: "RateTypeID", type: "number", editable: false, nullable: false },
                                c: { field: "c", nullable: true },
                                Type: { type: "string" },
                                basedon: { type: "string" },
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: check the column names you mention.. what you need `Type` or `UnitType` / `based` or `based on`

Comment: hi @swapnilnax, I am trying to do that but not working got same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i am analyse my data and i got the solution as follow:

In following data has been problem because `RateTypeID` property use as a parent so same and duplicate values found in this field it will give an error `Maximum call stack size exceeded`

```
var bindingData = [{ "RateTypeID": 1, "childto": null, "UnitType": "abc af f ", "basedon": "xyz" },
                { "RateTypeID": 1, "childto": 1, "UnitType": "pqr adf asd", "basedon": "dsaf" },
                { "RateTypeID": 2, "childto": 1, "UnitType": "mno asfsd  sd ", "basedon": "xyasdfz" }];
```

> **Parent fields** value must be **unique** for tree List in kendo.

Comment: But ParentKey is suppose to be share by multiple children, how can it be unique!